# How to fix - await not waiting

Tags: javascript, mongodb, promise, async-await

When I'm running an async function I want to use an await declaration not inside "then" but like:

```
const todayTotalVisitor = await getLastDayVisitors();
```

in that way, the await is not waiting.

```
async function sumMonth() {

const today = new Date();
if (today.getDate() == 1) return 0;
else {
    const todayTotalVisitor = await getLastDayVisitors();

    //query - last yestardy
    Counter.find({date: {$gte: beforeYesterday, $lt:yesterday 
    }}).then((result1) => {

        //get the totalVisitors of yestardy
        const monthlyYestardy = result1[0].monthly;
        //get today total visitor
        return todayTotalVisitor + monthlyYestardy;

    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });     
}}
```

In that way todayTotalVisitor is undefined.

getLastDayVisitors:

```
async function getLastDayVisitors() {

//query - last yestardy
Counter.find({date: {$gte: beforeYesterday, $lt:yesterday 
}}).then((result1) => {

//get the totalVisitors of yestardy
const TotalVisitorYesterday = result1[0].totalVisitors;

//query - general
Counter.find({name: 'general' }).then((result2) => {

    //get the totalVisitors overall
    const TotalVisitorOverAll = result2[0].totalVisitors;
    //return the delta
    return ( TotalVisitorOverAll-TotalVisitorYesterday);

}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
}).catch((err) => {
console.log(err);
});
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: does `getLastDayVisitors` return a Promise correctly that resolves to the value you require? ... in other words, what Dan wrote below :p

Comment: Can you show the code for `getLastDayVisitors`?

Comment: also, `return Counter.find({date...` as your method does not wait for the promise wherever it is getting called.

Comment: What exactly makes you think that todayTotalVisitor is undefined? Where do you log it? I think the bigger problem here is that your function simply doesn't return anything, so its result will always be undefined

Comment: This is so hard to read. I lost track of which function I'm in

Comment: simply add return before `Counter.find` in `getLastDayVisitors` - actually it's a little more complex than that

Comment: Or add an `await` inside your `async` function. This will essentially do the same thing. This would also simplify your code. Typically I wouldn't mix up `Promise` syntax and `async` `await`, use one or the other.

Comment: This is mixing patterns here either use `Promise and then()` or use `async/await` with your functions. Also `Model.find().exec()` would give you full promise so that you can do `const result = await Model.find().exec()`

Answer (score 2):

Your getLastDayVisitors  isn't returning anything not is it awaiting anything, therefore the promise  resolves to `undefined` immediately without waiting for any asynchrony to finish

change getLastDayVisitors to use await, since it already is async

The other changes are purely to use await in async instead of await and .then - use one or the other

```
async function getLastDayVisitors() {
    const result1 = await Counter.find({date: {$gte: beforeYesterday, $lt:yesterday }});
    //get the totalVisitors of yestardy
    const TotalVisitorYesterday = result1[0].totalVisitors;
    //query - general
    const result2 = await Counter.find({name: 'general' })
    //get the totalVisitors overall
    const TotalVisitorOverAll = result2[0].totalVisitors;
    //return the delta
    return ( TotalVisitorOverAll-TotalVisitorYesterday);
}
```

also rewrite `sumMonth` since it is `async` too

```
async function sumMonth() {
    const today = new Date();
    if (today.getDate() == 1) return 0;
    const todayTotalVisitor = await getLastDayVisitors();
    //query - last yestardy
    const result1 = await Counter.find({date: {$gte: beforeYesterday, $lt:yesterday }})
    //get the totalVisitors of yestardy
    const monthlyYestardy = result1[0].monthly;
    //get today total visitor
    return todayTotalVisitor + monthlyYestardy;
}
```

note, I've removed error handling, since where you had it would probably cause more problems than fix!

using sumMonth like

```
sumMonth()
.then(result => doSomethingWitf(result))
.catch(err => handleTheError(err));
```

or if using it in an async function

```
try {
    result = await sumMonth();
    // do something with it
} catch(err) {
    // handle err here
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the wrong placement of `(` in the "usage" example :p

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. Can you explain why it's not working in the first place 
(why the integration with the "then" in the body of the function didn't do the work?)

Ori